# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I am new on Android Development environment so need help from the experts.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
```

Gson library included in project but when calling Gson from a method inside the project getting the error like ths

Comment: did u put that jar file in libs folder

Comment: Download the jar and it to build path. add the jar to the libs folder of the project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a couple of reasons that this could be happening:

a) The library jar file is not being included

b) The wrong version of the jar file is being included

c) (if you are using maven) Another jar file is pulling in a newer/different version of the jar file

d) Your class path does not include the jar file.

A good starting point is to open the library jar file and see if you can actually see the class file in it.
If you are using maven then you should view the dependency tree to see if there are any conflicts using:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Answer (score 4):

1. [Down load the latest version of gason.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)
2. Add the jar of gason to the project[Eclipse: project proprieties => Java Build Path => Libraries =>Add External JARs]
3. check the gason.jar in Order and Export

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
java -cp gson.jar: JavaClassFile
```

Notice the `:` after `gson.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

put the jar file in web-inf/lib,not the lib

Answer (score 0):

A couple of reasons for the issue:

1. .aar Library: if the code involving Gson is in a .aar that is included in an application project as a library;  in this case, the application should also add gson as a dependency

reason: .aar libs do not propagate dependencies [transitively](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

2. proguard: wrong proguard rules required by gson, correct rules can be found [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)