# I am getting “java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson” error even though it is defined in my classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlf4Z.png)

I have already added the jar file into my eclipse build path but getting the same error when I tried with Maven test , Chrome has started and throws this error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420643/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gson-gson)

Comment: Build path is only used when building your project and not when running it. Is the GSON JAR file included in your run configuration?